# Multivariable Calculus Chain Rule

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am getting ready to write a notebook for the chain rule in Multivariable Calculus for my students. I do know:

```
Clear[x, y, z, t];
x = 2 t^2;
y = 3 - t^3;
z = x^2 + y^2;
D[z, t]
```

Or:

```
Clear[x, y, z, u, v];
x[u_, v_] = u^2 + v^2;
y[u_, v_] = u^2 - v^2;
z[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2;
D[z[x[u, v], y[u, v]], v]
```

But do folks have other suggestions and/or examples?

For example, might someone show that if $f(x)=x^2+y^2$ and $x=u^2-uv+v^2$ and $y=u^2+2uv-3v^2$, then the answer for $\partial f/\partial u$ is held to $(2x)(2u-v)+(2y)(2u+2v)$, which would help students with their intermediate steps.

And I think there are some that like to use Dt to do the chain rule?

**Update**

Just getting ready to teach the chain rule and although the Alexei Boulbitch example in the answer works:

```
Clear[x, y, u, v, f];
x = u^2 - u*v + v^2;
y = u^2 + 2 u*v - 3 v^2;
f = x^2 + y^2;
D[f, u] /. {x -> X, y -> Y}

(*  2 (2 u - v) X + 2 (2 u + 2 v) Y  *)
```

But this does not:

```
Clear[x, y, f, t]
x = 2 t;
y = t^2;
f = x^2 y + x y^2;
D[f, t] /. {x -> X, y -> Y}

(* 16 t^3 + 10 t^4 *)
```

Wondering what is the difference between this and the Alexei Boulbitch answer, which works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really sure that I understand your aim, but as to the simple example in the end of your question, this seems to do the job:

```
    Clear[x, y, u, v, f];
x = u^2 - u*v + v^2;
y = u^2 + 2 u*v - 3 v^2;
f = x^2 + y^2;
D[f, u] /. {x -> X, y -> Y}

(*  2 (2 u - v) X + 2 (2 u + 2 v) Y  *)
```

Have fun!

**Later comment**: To address your later question: In the first example the trick worked, since the expressions of the result:

```
    Clear[x, y, u, v, f];
x = u^2 - u*v + v^2;
y = u^2 + 2 u*v - 3 v^2;
f = x^2 + y^2;


 D[f, u]

    (* 
 2 (2 u + 2 v) *(u^2 + 2 u v - 3 v^2)* + 2 (2 u - v) *(u^2 - u v + v^2)* 
 *)
```

already contained the combinations exactly equal to x and y. I pointed them out by the asterixes in the answer. This enables one to directly apply the replacement. Your new example is different. If you make the calculation:

```
 Clear[x, y, f, t]
x = 2 t;
y = t^2;
f = x^2 y + x y^2;
D[f, t]

(*  16 t^3 + 10 t^4   *)
```

the result has no such a form as the previous one, and even more, one can represent its terms in many different ways as some products of x and y. One should decide, what he wants to achieve. 
What about the following:

```
 Clear[x, y, f, t]

f = x[t]^2 y[t] + x[t] y[t]^2;
Factor /@ (D[f, t] // Collect[#, {y'[t], x'[t]}] &)

(*  y[t] (2 x[t] + y[t]) Derivative[1][x][t] + 
 x[t] (x[t] + 2 y[t]) Derivative[1][y][t]   *)
```

?? Is it not closer to the chain rule?

If this is not what you are after, explain me please your target in more details.

Have fun!

Comment: Nice example, just the type of thing I am looking for. Interesting approach.

Comment: Just did an update to my post and wondering why your technique does not work this time.

Comment: @David Please have a look into the edit.

Comment: Alexei, thanks for the help. :-)